# ubuntu network manager swanstrong VPN - how to enter double quote into preshared key?

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, vpn

I have two strongswan VPN's (or l2tp/ipsec) with same configuration and I can't connect to second one which uses pre-shared key which contains double quote, ie. "

I can connect to first one without double quote in preshared key. When I change preshared key intentionaly to wrong one, output in syslog describing error is very similar to output of second VPN connect try.

Thus I think I need to escape double quote in preshared key somehow in order to make it work, however these didn't help:

- backslash before double quote
- entering preshared key in single quotes
- trying to use base64 format 0sbase64encodedpsk - see https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/PskSecret

Any idea?

I use Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver

Answer (score 1):

In the [strongswan docs](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/PskSecret), it says "The sequence cannot contain newline or double-quote characters"

So you'll either have to:

- convince them that such an unstandard policy is foolish (unlikely)
- just get another key that has no newlines and double quotes
- patch it

Comment: Thanks for reply @Peter, on same page there is also: 

_Alternatively, preshared secrets can be represented as hexadecimal or Base64 encoded binary values._

Also kindly see that I already posted link to that page in my question.